# Moving Mailer action to Resque queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque-scheduler

A controller action calls `TextMailer.contact(fg, mailing).deliver_now`, however this needs to be moved into a background job at a determined time with resque-scheduler gem.

Thus the controller action would now invoke:

```
 Resque.enqueue_at(@time, DelayedMailer, @fg.id, @mailing.id)
```

a new rake task is set with Resque...

```
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/resque_schedule.yml")
  ENV['QUEUES'] = *
end
```

to run a `delayed_mailer` job

```
class DelayedMailer
  @queue = :mail
    def self.perform(time, fg_id, mailing_id)
    fg = Fg.where('id = ?', fg_id).first
    mailing = Mailing.where('id = ?', mailing_id).first
    TextMailer.contact(fg, mailing).deliver_now
 end
```

There are two syntactic elements which need clarifying.

1) does the perform method need to invoke the time value (it appears counter-intuitive as calling Resque with `enqueue_at` explicitly gives a time key, which implicitly is not necessary to repeat)  ?

2) can the ActionMailer method be invoked without futher change, as it was running before, or does the queue somehow interrupt some logic ?

Comment: I'd recommend you to read about ActiveJob, you can configure Resque as the backend and ActionMailer will support async delivery methods that automatically use Resque.

Comment: well, yes, I have.  the rails guide states 'you can define perform with as many arguments as you want'... and while the `resque-scheduler` github page defines enqueue_at, it does not state whether the original at-time call needs to be invoked in `perform` (I assume not because the job is already stored at that point "delayed queue is stored in redis and is persisted").

Answer (score 1):

You can configure resque to work with ActionMailer.

1. Add `gem 'resque'` to your gemfile.
2. Make change to adapter in `application.rb` - `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :resque`
3. Use the following to generate a job - `rails g job SendEmail`

---

```
class SendEmail< ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(fg_id, mailing_id)
    fg = Fg.where('id = ?', fg_id).first
    mailing = Mailing.where('id = ?', mailing_id).first
    TextMailer.contact(fg, mailing).deliver_now
  end
end
```

---

In your controller, you can do

```
SendEmail.set(wait: 10.seconds).perform_later(@fg.id, @mailing.id)
```

Comment: This is slightly off the mark. As the questions states, each mail is stamped " at a determined time" the `@time` instance variable. which is why `enqueue_at` is invoked, as per resque-scheduler gem. Thus the two questions. As it is first time I notice a reference to `config.active_job.queue_adapter`, please justify.  Right now my queues are being generated without such addition.

Comment: `config.active_job.queue_adapter` is for setting the `queueing` backend.

Comment: Why are you setting `@time`, when the job is being `enqueued` ?

Comment: `enqueue_at`.  it is being scheduled at a pre-determined time, as the resque-scheduler gem allows.

Comment: For your question #2, you don't have to make any change to the logic for `ActionMailer` method. It'll continue to behave the same, only the invocation will change.